# How to convert a POJO to map / map to POJO in Android

Tags: android, hashmap, pojo, apache-commons-beanutils

My Question is : 
is there a tool like BeanUtils(apache) can be used in ANDROID? Please give me some hint.

```
//here is a simple POJO
public class Pojo{
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private double money;
//some set/get method ............
}
//and 
 Pojo pojo1 = new Pojo();
 pojo1.setName("jack");
 pojo.setAge(90);
 pojo.setMoney(99.78);
//then I have a blank map:
 HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

I want to copy the valaues in pojo1 to map1;
and I want to copy a map with values to an blank Pojo object;

the keys in the map is the same as fields of Pojo;

in the process of map to pojo , there should be a auto(but simple) class convert(such as String to int and so on);

I know there is beanutils from apache, but it can't work in ANDROID.

My english is not good , and just learn java for half year. I spend 2 days to find such tool.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Map? (Serialize it)?

Comment: the case is:  the android client we developed will connect with server. the protrol is xml. i want to make xml to pojo (and pojo to xml). there to many different pojo. so i want to to make xml to map the map to pojo( pojo to map , map to xml).  BTW the xml is not simple , it has some levels.

Comment: Why don't you use Fasterxml Jackson to take your POJO to XML? Then you can use the library to generate your XML or JSON (if you want do use JSON).

Comment: covert pojo to xml is simple. but covert a xml(it may contain many pojo) to pojo is not simple.( the server will response a string with the format of xml , i need to make it to many pojo)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) to do your project would probably be best. You will need to create classes for your XML to decode into. If you don't have classes on the server side, you can use JAXB to convert XML to Java classes.

To make Jackson be able to deserialze your classes add `@XmlRootElement` to your root classes. Then you just create an instance of an `XmlMapper` and user the serialize/deserialze methods.

Another perk of using Jackson is that you will be able to convert to JSON if your services ever need to be more light weight.

If you don't think it will work then post some samples into your post or a [Gist](http://gist.github.com) to review the code and find any problems that you are running into.

Refs:

- [Jackson processor for java bean to json\xml serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849540/jackson-processor-for-java-bean-to-json-xml-serialization)
- http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome
- http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/03/entry_467.html